# "View [PDF (pdflatex)]" (Ctrl+R) -- PDF not opening smoothly

Tags: lyx

Previously in LyX 2.2, when I ran "View [PDF (pdflatex)]" (Ctrl+R), the PDF almost always smoothly opened in Adobe Acrobat.

But now with LyX 2.3, when I run it, I often get this error message in Adobe Acrobat: "There was an error opening this document. This file cannot be found."

By repeatedly hitting Ctrl+R (sometimes 10+ times), the PDF does eventually open. But this is quite inconvenient. How can I fix this?

Comment: Strange, I have no heard of this before. You might consider trying a different PDF viewer, e.g., SumatraPDF, just to narrow down whether the bug is present with all PDF viewers or just Acrobat. That might give a hint at fixing the issue with Acrobat.

Comment: @scottkosty: Yes I just tried Foxit and it seems to be fine. // I think I read at some old forum that it's something to do with Acrobat not being given the full path name. Do you think that might be a reason for this bug? If so how can I get LyX to give Acrobat the full path name?

Comment: Another possible clue: If I have (all instances of) Adobe Acrobat closed, then this bug doesn't occur (hitting Ctrl+R in LyX smoothly opens the PDF as desired). But it's when I have Adobe Acrobat already open that this bug often occurs.

Comment: Just to note that I otherwise have zero problems ever in opening any PDF in Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Those are helpful clues. The main clue is your original one, that LyX 2.2 worked for you. Indeed a lot has changed since 2.2. I wonder if it would be worth it for you to try LyX 2.4 development version to see if somehow it's better for that. That said, it's still in the early stages of the release so there's a lot of bugs to work out. But if you don't find any solution in the next few months, check back on 2.4 development and maybe give it a try. I'm sorry I don't have any other suggestions for how to debug what's going on.